# using typename with reinterpret_cast()

Tags: c++, c++14, reinterpret-cast, typename

How to create a typename that is the result of a reinterpret_cast?

For instance,

```
template<typename T1> class node{

public:

using null_sp2node = typename reinterpret_cast<shared_ptr<node<T1>>>(NULL);

};
```

The above generates the following compiler error:

> error: expected a qualified name after 'typename'

Comment: For those who don't know where to put `typename` while using `reinterpret_cast`:
`reinterpret_cast<typename ClassA<T>>(things_to_convert)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast` returns a *value*, not a type. Specifically, it is an expression. If you want to get the type of an expression, the correct tool is `decltype`:

```
using null_sp2node = decltype(reinterpret_cast<shared_ptr<node<T1>>>(NULL));
```

However, because the result of a `reinterpret_cast<T>` is an expression of the type `T`, there's really no point to this compared to just:

```
using null_sp2node = shared_ptr<node<T1>>;
```

Of course, since `reinterpret_cast<shared_ptr<node<T1>>>(NULL)` is il-formed to begin with, it really doesn't matter. You cannot `reinterpret_cast` a null pointer constant to a non-pointer type (except for certain integer types).